# What is the difference between 們 and 们 for marking plurals?

Tags: difference, traditional-vs-simplified, orthography

I've seen native speakers refer to "we" as both 我们 and 我們, so I was wondering if there's any difference in meaning or when to use one plural marker or the other.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that 门/們 is not a generic plural marker. It's used mostly for pronouns (我 vs 我们), and it has very limited use beyond that (The only other use I can think of: it can be added to nouns when a speaker is a addressing an audience, indicating mutual inclusion in that group, e.g, Hu Jintao addressing the audience beginning with "同志们，朋友们" ＝ "Comrades, friends, ...")

Comment: Thanks, Stumpy. I haven't seen them use plurals for other nouns so far, so I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: I wonder why someone would downvote this question..... :S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

我们 and 我們 are same, except 们 is simplified character, and 們 is traditional character.

See this for more details: [Simplified Chinese characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese_characters)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I obviously know less than the basics of chinese :D But I'm learning... slowly... ^_^ If you would please upvote my question, I'll gain part of the necessary reputation to upvote your answer, helping move this stackexchange out of beta. ;)

Comment: @msb Done as requested. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Based on 孤影萍踪's explanation about 們/们, try to show you more detail:

1. 他們 ta1 men0 = they (at least one man)
2. 他們倆 ta1 men0 lia0 = they two (at least one man)
3. 她們 ta1 men0 = they (all women)
4. 牠們 ta1 men0 = they (animals)
5. 鐵哥們 tie3 ge1 men0 = a male close friend, sometimes female too
6. 圖們江 tu2 men2 jiang1 = proper noun, name of a [river](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumen_River) near North Korea
7. 它們 ta1 men0 = they (things)
8. 你們 ni3 men0 = you (more than one)
9. 娘兒們 niang2 er0 men0 = a woman or some women (sometimes derogatory, sometimes just friendly)
10. 諾們罕 nuo4 men2 han4 = [the Nomonhan Incident](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AB%BE%E9%96%80%E7%BD%95%E6%88%B0%E5%BD%B9), a battle between Japan and USSR in 1939
11. 老哥兒們 lao3 ge1 er0 men0 = buddy, in a friendly way, sometimes not so friendly
12. 哥們兒 ge1 mer0 = dude, in a friendly way, sometimes not so friendly
13. 哥兒們 ge1 er0 men0 = "hey my dear friends"
14. 孩兒們 hai2 er0 men0 = "my dear children"
15. 渠們 qu2 men0 = they (guess it's dialect)
16. 小哥兒們 xiao2 ge1 er0 men0 = handsome young boys
17. 小姐們兒 xiao2 jie3 mer0 = sisters or sometimes whores
18. 這們 zhe4 men4 (this kind of... e.g. 西遊記˙第二十回 「那老兒 你這們大年紀 全不曉事」Journey to the West, Chapter 20, "[Mondey King shouted] Hey, that old dude, look at you, such a old, but doesn't know anything!")
19. 人們 ren2 men0 = people
20. 咱們 zan2 men0 = we
21. 俺們 an3 men0 = we
22. 爺們兒 ye2 mer0 = (a man or husband, emphasizing maturity)
23. 爺們 ye2 men0 = (a man or husband, emphasizing maturity, see also: 紅樓夢˙第二十七回 「你別胡說 他是個爺們家 揀了我們的東西 自然該還的 我拿甚麼謝他呢」Dream of the Red Chamber, Chapter 27, "Don't you talk non-sense, he's a man, picked our stuff, sure he should hand it back, why should I thank him??")
24. 爺兒們 ye2 er0 men0 = (a man or husband, emphasizing maturity)
25. 我們 wo3 men0 or wo3 men2 = we
26. 們渾 men4 hun2 = buxom

---

### Reference

[1] Entry of 們 in [教育部重編國語辭典修訂本線上版 National Chinese Dictionary Online, Ministry of Education, Taiwan](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/)

[2] Related words of 們 in [教育部重編國語辭典修訂本線上版 National Chinese Dictionary Online, Ministry of Education, Taiwan](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/)